# Imported function that takes one argument displays error that 2 arguments were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a class file called `importDemo.py` that is at the same directory as my main file called `FunctionsDemo.py`

Here is the content of importDemo.py:

```
class basicFunction:

    myName = "John"

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("Constructor has been called")

    def greet(name):
        print(f"Hi there {name}\n\n")
```

And this is the main FunctionsDemo.py file:

```
from importDemo import basicFunction as func

firstObj = func()
firstObj.greet(firstObj.myName)

func.greet("Ben")
print(firstObj.myName)
```

When I try to run FunctionsDemo.py, it displays this error

> `TypeError: greet() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? I only given `greet()` one argument?
I was hoping I can trigger both constructor and greet() with no errors.

EDIT: I got confused and mistakenly used instance and class functions

if I used `func()`, it goes without saying that I need to include the self in my function. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You forgot the `self` parameter in `def greet`: `def greet(self, name):`

Comment: You need to decide whether `greet` is an instance method or a class method. You can't call them both with a single argument.

Comment: I see, maybe that is why when I try `def greet(self, name):` it gives me the error `TypeError: greet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python class a method parameters start with one default parameter called self which reference the class object. You can use the self to access public variables declared within the class so in your code you should include the self in your greet method list of parameters like so:

```
   def greet(self, name):
          print(f"Hi there {name}\n\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `greet` as a method, right? Then you should define it like that:

```
def greet(self,name):
        print(f"Hi there {name}\n\n")
```